# MongoDB password with "@" in it

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB database with a username and password using Mongoose in Node.js. All the docs say that the connection string should look like

```
  mongodb://username:password@host:port/db
```

However, the password contains the '@' character in it. How can I make a connection string out of this that mongoose will understand? Can I escape the  '@' in the password or is there another method of connecting I have to use?

Comment: Have you tried it? Maybe it uses the last @ it finds.

Comment: Nope - doesn't work. Enoding them a %40 doesn't work either.

Comment: I would recommend to change the password to one that does not include @ character.

Comment: Yes, that would work but I'd love to see a real solution.

Comment: does escaping with a slash work ?  "\@" ?

Comment: No, that generates an illegal character error.

Comment: @SylvainDefresne There will be no '@' character in the password. Its the format of structuring the URL for connecting MongoDB using Mongoose Connection object.. Please go through this link : http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: @AmolMKulkarni: I know this is the format the mongoose use to specify connection. But the OP wanted to know how he could use a password that contained an '@'? This a password like "p@ssw0rd" (which is a lame password). The url would be "monbgodb://username:p@ssw0rd@host:port/db" which is mis-interpreted by mongoose (ie. it splits at the first @ instead of the last).

Comment: @SylvainDefresne: Thanks for update from your end. Its correct The url would be "monbgodb://username:p@ssw0rd@host:port/db"

Comment: Got misunderstood by one wrong answer here, which is already downvoted

Comment: The character `@` in your password need to be encoded in the URL. The encoded `@` character is `%40`. However, the `%` character need to be encoded too. So, if your password is, lets say, `p@ss`, the final encoded password should be `p%2540ss`

Comment: { useNewUrlParser: true } did the trick for me

Comment: @SylvainDefresne how can you change the password in Mongo `Atlas`?

Comment: @SylvainDefresne It is in "add new database user" in "atlas cloud".

Answer (score 200):

Use this syntax:

```
// use %40 for @
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:p%40ssword@host:port/dbname?authSource=admin", { 
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }, function(err, db) {

    }
);
```

Comment: This answer should get more love, it's really just converting to the @ symbol to %40 that does the trick.

Comment: I missed the `{uri_decode_auth: true}` at first glance, but it worked once I noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: For noobies, `{uri_decode_auth: true}` should be passed as a separate object if you're in NodeJS and using mongoDB's native driver.

Comment: the options [uri_decode_auth] is not supported as of driver version 3.1

Comment: It gives the options [uri_decode_auth] is not supported,
using mongoose latest

Comment: uri_decode_auth option is removed but this solution works without it

Comment: How is it a solution if password can be anything and should not be stored as clear text in code. This answer does not explain how to generally fix the issue - manually search for `@` sign? That code smells

Comment: Yes it should work. This is from mongoDB official documentation ```mongodb://myDBReader:D1fficultP%40ssw0rd@mongodb0.example.com:27017/?authSource=admin```

Comment: if anyone is wondering escapes are supported in .env

Comment: You saved my life in 2023. The solution works for me.

Answer (score 86):

If your password has special characters:

```
const dbUrl = `mongodb://adminUsername:${encodeURIComponent('adminPassword')}@localhost:27017/mydb`;
```

Comment: This is the answer that should get more love as it fixes the complete problem, not just the very specific use case of the OP.

Comment: This is working great, just for info if someone missed it, you still need to pass {useNewUrlParser: true} as the second argument when connecting using mongoose.connect()

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer as this takes care of the root cause -- special characters within the pass/username require encoding as the mongo connection string uses the URI spec. RFC2396

Answer (score 32):

Use the `options` parameter of the [`mongoose.connect`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-connect) call to specify the password instead of including it in the URL string:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',
                 {user: 'username', pass: 'p@ssword'},
                 callback);
```

Comment: I like this approach because typing one more line doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 7):

Try this one, my friends:

```
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/test?authSource=admin",
                     {user: 'viettd', pass: 'abc@123'});
```

`test` is my db name 
`admin` is my the db for authenticating 
`viettd` is my username 
`abc@123` is my password

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced the same issue. I have solved by adding encoded password into connection string. And it works just well.

(1) Encode your password from https://www.url-encode-decode.com
(2) Replace your password with encoded one.
(3) It should work well.

For example:
Actual Password: ABCDEX$KrrpvDzRTy`@drf.';3X
Encoded Password: ABCDEX%24KrrpvDzRTy%60%40drf.%27%3B3X

mongodb://user1:ABCDEX%24KprpvDzRTy%60%40drf.%27%3B3X@dstest.com:1234,ds1234-test.com:19889/mongo-dev?replicaSet=rs-ds123546978&ssl=true',

Comment: not the best advice, to recommend sending the password to an untrusted source...

Comment: As @guyarad said, you shouldn't expose your database password, and is not suitable if you change passwords regularly. And the reason for this comment is that, you don't need other softwares / sites to do that, `encodeURIComponent()` is the built-in function that can do the job.

Answer (score 5):

use pwd instead pass, that worked for me for version3.2

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test',
                 {user: 'username', pwd: 'p@ssword'},
                 callback);
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use Mongodb native Node.js driver, this is what works for me as of 3.1 driver version. Assume your url doesn't contain auth info.

```
MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
let options = {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'your_usr',
        password: 'your_pwd'
    }
};
MongoClient.connect(url, options, callback);
```

Or if you wanna include auth info in your url, do this:

```
let url = "mongodb://username:" + encodeURIComponent("p@ssword") + "@localhost:27017/database"
```

Answer (score 3):

None of the solutions mentioned above worked for me. I researched it further and found out that I had to include the useNewUrlParser parameter.

```
mongoose.connect(db, {
    useNewUrlParser : true
    },
    err => {
    if (err){
        console.error('Error: ' + err)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Connected to MongoDb')
    }
})
```

From what I understand, you need a specific version of MongoDB in order to use this. For more details, check [Avoid “current URL string parser is deprecated” warning by setting useNewUrlParser to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars)

It is to get rid of the warning but clearly the version also affect the required parameter.

I haven't tested all special characters but it definitely works with '@#$'.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes you need to connect to the DB using other [tools](https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-files-utils) that accept string only as connection string. so just change the @ sign with %40

Comment: for example (dont worry dummy user and pass) change this: mongodb://kipkip:Nolalola22@@ds031223.mlab.com:3d223/mishlo to: mongodb://kipkip:Nolalola22%40@ds031223.mlab.com:3d223/mishlo

Answer (score 1):

Also, if your password contains a percentage, %,
Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that octet to be used as data within a URI

for example, if your password is John%Doe, the new transformed password will be John%25Doe or
If password is Paul%20Wait, New Password will be Paul%2520Wait

```
mongoClient.connect("mongodb://username:John%25Doe@host:port/dbname", function(err, db) {
// password is John%Doe
    }`enter code here`
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires an extra dependency, but it was what finally worked for me.

Add `mongodb-uri` to your project and the following lines to your code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongodbUri = require('mongodb-uri')
let mongooseUri = mongodbUri.formatMongoose(config.mongo.uri)
mongoose.connect(mongooseUri, config.mongo.options)
```

I found this suggestion in `mongoose`'s GitHub issue [#6044](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6044#issuecomment-384657626).

Answer (score 0):

Use this,

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true}).then(()=>console.log("DB connected"));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the username or password includes the at sign @, colon :, slash /, or the percent sign % character, use [percent encoding](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1).

Mongo Docs:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Answer (score 0):

I was attempting this in python and I had a similar error. This worked for me.

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://username:12%40password@ip:27017/sample_db") 
db = client.sample_db
# print the number of documents in a collection
print(db.collection.count())
```

12%40password represents your password and assumes it has a special character (e.g. @ - represented by %40)  - username is your mongodb username , ip - your ip address and sample_db the database under mongodb that you wish to connect to.

Comment: this works only for pymongo python. Not in nodeJs.

Answer (score 0):

**This one worked for me**

*This one is a MongoDB 2020 Update*
If You're using a separate env file then just add your

```
mongoose.connect('url',
{
    useNewUrlParser: true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I faced something similar, but I was not able to find any way around it other than avoiding special characters in password. I tried other special characters (^ % &) none of them works with the password in URL string. But the MongoDB [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) says only

```
: / ? # [ ] @
```

these characters need to be percent-encoded.

I tried encoding most of them in my password combinations, but none of them are working.

Answer (score -3):

To connect to a MongoDB database and avoid issues with special characters like "@" in your password, you have a few options:

1. **Change Your Password:** The simplest approach is to change your MongoDB password to one that does not include special characters. This can help you avoid complications in your connection string.
2. **encodeURIComponent:** If you need to keep the special characters in your password, you can use the `encodeURIComponent` function in JavaScript to encode your password. Here's how you can use it in your connection string:

   ```js
   const username = 'your_username';
   const password = 'your@password'; // Note the special character "@" in the password
   const encodedPassword = encodeURIComponent(password);

   const connectionString = `mongodb://${username}:${encodedPassword}@your-mongodb-host:27017/your-database`;
   ```