# handle @ in mongodb connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have connection string

```
<add key="MongoDBConnectionString" value="mongodb://user:password@123@127.0.0.1/?safe=true"/>
```

password is `password@123` so host is parsing 123@127.0.0.1, how can i handle @ in credential

**Edit**
I have tried to escape it but still same problem

```
 <add key="MongoDBConnectionString" value="mongodb://user:password&#64;123@127.0.0.1/?safe=true"/>
```

**Edit**
Thanks to alexjamesbrown for helping, following escaping working for me.

```
<add key="MongoDBConnectionString" value="mongodb://user:password%40123@127.0.0.1/?safe=true"/>
```

Comment: have you tried escaping the @ to %40 (in the password)

Comment: According to this question: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it

It won't work.

Comment: @alexjamesbrown : working for me. may be because I am using C# driver not node.

Comment: Which is working, escaping to %40?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB password with "@" in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I posted this as an answer before, but it converted it to a comment...

Escape your @ sign to `%40`  (in your password string.)

As per the comments, I believe this will work using the C# driver, but might not work when using other drivers (mongoose on node.js for example)