# How to init native Mongo in NodeJS with at Sign in password

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to figure out how to connect to my mongodb db using the native node mongo driver and I have two issues:

- My password contains an @ sign making it break the normal user:pass@host connection string format
- How do I list databases from what I have below?

Any ideas on how to address this?

Here is an attempt which does not work:

```
var Mongo = require('mongodb');

var server = new Mongo.Server('mongodb://myhost', 27017);
var db = new Mongo.Db('test', server);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    console.log(err); //unable to connect
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, I was able to resolve this with the connection option `uri_decode_auth`. You will need to `encodeURIComponent(password)` before embedding it in the connection string.

Here's a complete working example:

```
MongoClient.connect(connection, { uri_decode_auth: true }, function(err, db) {

  if(err) {
    return cb(err);
  }

  db.admin().listDatabases(function(err, dbs) {
    console.log(dbs);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335978/handle-in-mongodb-connection-string):

> The solution is to replace `@` with `%40`

*I tested with the C# driver and it works like a charm.*