# How do I escape `@` letter from SQL password in connection URI

Tags: python, sql, mongodb, sqlalchemy

when you connect to mongodb using python from SQLAlchamey, we use

```
mongodb://username:password@host/database
```

If my password is `P@ssword` , how can I escape the `@` letter.

In my case it is breaking the connection because of this.

Other than changing the password is there any way?

Comment: Sorry, I can't post comments but this may help:

 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335978/handle-in-mongodb-connection-string

Answer (score 15):

Assuming that URLs in the mongodb scheme function like normal URLs, the password part must be URL-encoded.  Specifically, @ would be encoded as %40.  This quoting can be performed by Python's urllib:

```
>>> urllib.quote("P@ssword")
"P%40ssword"
```

Related: [URL: Username with @](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10050877/url-username-with)