# Auth failed error when specifying database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to connect to a `mongodb` from my web application. However, I get an `auth failed error` from mongo when I specify the database I want to connect to. If I do not specify the db, then to connection is successful.

I have checked the spelling and if the database exits with the mongo command line `show dbs`

```
var dbURI = 'mongodb://root:pwd@localhost:27017/dbname';
mongoose.connect(dbURI, function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
});

C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:245
        throw message;
              ^
MongoError: auth failed
    at Object.toError (C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\utils.js:114:11)
    at C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1130:31
    at C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\db.js:1847:9
    at Server.Base._callHandler (C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\base.js:445:41)
    at C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:478:18
    at MongoReply.parseBody (C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\responses\mongo_reply.js:68:5)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\server.js:436:20)
    at emit (events.js:95:17)
    at null.<anonymous> (C:\Users\David\Documents\Bitbucket\productWebsite\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongodb\connection\connection_pool.js:201:13)
    at emit (events.js:98:17)
```

I'm using Bitnami Mean stack for Windows

Can someone tell me what I am forgetting?

Comment: Have you added that authentication to that database?

Comment: Yes, I have connected to the database with Robomongo GUI and the native mongo console. The credentials work

Comment: Is it possible that the user name or password have characters that need escaped? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335978/handle-in-mongodb-connection-string

Comment: As a follow up, if that's the case consider the fact that you're going to have to set the `uri_decode_auth` option on the `MongoClient` when connecting. http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html

Comment: I do not use special characters

Comment: @David Can you help me on how did you connect bitnami mongodb to robomongo?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It matters which database you try to authenticate to. Authenticate to the database where the user was created. You can switch to using other databases once authenticated.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to do something like this...

```
var opt = {
        user: config.username,
        pass: config.password,
        auth: {
            authdb: 'admin'
        }
    };

var connection = mongoose.createConnection(config.database.host, 'mydatabase', config.database.port, opt);
```

'authdb' option is the database you created the user under.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, I found that the reason might be the version difference between the mongoose and mongoDB. In my package.json the mongoose version is the **3.8.5** and my mongoDB version is 3.0.4, I changed the mongoose version **3.8.5** to **4.1.5** and ran the command:

```
npm update
```

and ran the app, that worked for me.