# Connecting Westorm with Mongolab db

Tags: mongoose, webstorm, mlab

I am creating a project using Webstorm with mongoose library installed. Developing on my localhost with **mongodb**, my connection string was:

```
database: "mongodb://127.0.0.1/mydatabase"
```

Everything works fine. I am trying to move it to the web using a mongolad db.
I changed my connection string to the following:

```
database: "mongodb://myuser:mypass@dsXXXXXX.mongolab.com:XXXXXX/mydatabase"
```

I am getting an error in webstorm:

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: failed to connect to [chtr33:27017]
```

Removing the username and password does not throw the error, but of course I have no read/write permissions.

Comment: Which backend technology are you using? NodeJS? Also it might be an error which is thrown while db connection.

Comment: node.js not sure mongoose supports connection string with auth, reading up on it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out you cant use the @ char in the password (facepalm)

Comment: You can.  You just need to connect a little differently as shown  in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it

Answer (score 1):

You can simply replace '@' with '%40' in password in connection string.

It worked for me, I hope it would work for you too.