# mongoose error in connecting to mongodb after adding user authentication to mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, dbconnection

I am using mongodb on ubuntu 14.04 and I ran a command to add a user to a database and set readWrite permissions to it by the following command -

```
mongo
```

and then `use utthan-dev`
and then do

```
db.createUser(
    {
      user: "hladdha",
      pwd: "Hladdha@31",
      roles: [
         { role: "readWrite", db: "utthaan-dev" }
      ]
    }
)
```

Now, I am connecting in my express app by the following connection string -

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://hladdha:Hladdha@Demo@localhost/utthaan-dev');
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error('MongoDB connection error: ' + err);
    process.exit(-1);
    }
);
```

And now I am getting the following error in node console -

```
MongoDB connection error: MongoError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
```

How should I connect the mongoose to mongodb correctly no ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it

Comment: If the password has @ character you have to encode it

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Open mongodb comandline
Goto server location and write cmd
1.C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin
2. Mongo.exe

Step 2 Switch to user administrator

1. Write "use admin" command in cmd

Step 3. Create User with below command
1.db.createUser({ user: "UserName", pwd: "Password", roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "DatabaseName" } ] })
2.Then disconnect from the mongo shell (Ctrl+D)

Step 4. Add below line in mongod.cfg file below #security line
security:
authorization: "enabled"

Step 5. Restart MongoDbServer