# Using R to connecting to MongoDB password with '@'

Tags: r, mongolite

This is similar to the question here:
[MongoDB password with "@" in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it)

However, I'm using the R package mongolite to connect so I can't apply that solution. Any recommendations on how to modify it so that it still works for the *mongolite package*

For example if my username is: user1, and my password is: p@ssword, how would I write:

```
mongodb://user1:p@ssword@myip
```

Thank you!

Comment: Nope -- it uses I think the %40 and says authentication failed :-(

Answer (score 2):

I used this structure and worked for me

```
newdb <- mongo(collection= "name_collection", 
               db = "name_db", 
               url = "mongodb://user:password@your_ip:port_number/name_db", 
               verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: The question asks for a password with the `@` symbol in it. I don't think your solution solves it.

Comment: how do you find your_ip:port_number?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and solved it by escaping the @ in the password by using its corresponding `percent-encoding`, e.g. use`%40` to ecape it. So in your case:

```
mongodb://user1:p%40ssword@myip
```

should work.

Edit: I did not see you already had the answer in a comment :) The escape worked in my case so I assume you may have a mistake in either your username or password.

Answer (score 0):

In your p@ssword @ character is creating problem so replace it by %40 as suggested by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4455096/rapture