# How to solve mongodb altas ' querySrv ENODATA ' error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have been trying to connect to the MongoDB Atlas to my Node.js project for the last few hours and still couldn't connect to it yet.I've tried all the solutions that I found on the internet and none that solved my problems. How can I connect to the MongoDB Atlas ?

This is the error.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wcX9.png

Comment: How do you connect to the atlas?

Comment: I've tried with all the different methods(Node.js driver, mongoose, MongoDB Compass ) but it's always showing that error.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859035/accessing-a-mongodb-atlas-cluster-from-within-google-cloud-functions-console

Comment: Did  the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. So make sure your current **IP** address is added into your MongoDB cluster and make sure your credentials is the same as in the atlas. **Username** (User Privileges: Read and write to any db), **Password**, **dbname**)
2. Check your `dns` maybe You need to change them to for example ([OpenDNS](https://use.opendns.com/), Google DNS).
3. This issue occur when You often use `different`, `many`  internet connection
4. Sometimes it is enough to **update**: `mongodb`, `node.js & npm.`
5. Good Luck ;-) I hope it will help You!