# Avoid "current URL string parser is deprecated" warning by setting useNewUrlParser to true

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I have a database wrapper class that establishes a connection to some MongoDB instance:

```
async connect(connectionString: string): Promise<void> {
        this.client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString)
        this.db = this.client.db()
}
```

This gave me a warning:

> (node:4833) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

The `connect()` method accepts a `MongoClientOptions` instance as second argument. But it doesn't have a property called `useNewUrlParser`. I also tried to set those property in the connection string like this: `mongodb://127.0.0.1/my-db?useNewUrlParser=true` but it has no effect on those warning.

So how can I set `useNewUrlParser` to remove those warning? This is important to me since the script should run as cron and those warnings result in trash-mail spam.

I'm using `mongodb` driver in version `3.1.0-beta4` with corresponding `@types/mongodb` package in `3.0.18`. Both of them are the latest avaliable using `npm install`.

#### Workaround

Using an older version of mongodb driver:

```
"mongodb": "~3.0.8",
"@types/mongodb": "~3.0.18"
```

Comment: That's coming from the `beta` version which somehow got released on npm over the weekend. Don't worry about it until the API is actually finalized. You did the right thing installing a stable version.

Comment: above 3.0.0 of mongodb add simply 
 mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:portnumber/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })

Answer (score 447):

Check your `mongo` version:

```
mongo --version
```

If you are using version >= 3.1.0, change your `mongo` connection file to ->

```
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true })
```

or your mongoose connection file to ->

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/YourDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Ideally, it's a version 4 feature, but v3.1.0 and above are supporting it too. Check out [MongoDB GitHub](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/v3.1.0/lib/mongo_client.js#L112)  for details.

Comment: @AbhishekSinha Why with mongo >= 4.0.0? I'm using 3.6.5 and the annoying message has gone too.

Comment: Yup fixed that. Basically, it's a v4 feature but v3.1.0 and above supports the new feature as well.

Comment: This is the best, just wanted to add, if you have a callback, esp for error, just use this:
mongoose.connect(dbUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err) {
   console.log("mongoDB connected", err);
})

Answer (score 51):

As noted the `3.1.0-beta4` release of the driver got "released into the wild" a little early by the looks of things. The release is part of work in progress to support newer features in the MongoDB 4.0 upcoming release and make some other API changes.

One such change triggering the current warning is the `useNewUrlParser` option, due to some changes around how passing the connection URI actually works. More on that later.

Until things "settle down", it would probably be [advisable to "pin"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22345808/2313887) at least to the minor version for `3.0.x` releases:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "~3.0.8"
  }
```

That should stop the `3.1.x` branch being installed on "fresh" installations to node modules. If you already did install a "latest" release which is the "beta" version, then you should clean up your packages ( and `package-lock.json` ) and make sure you bump that down to a `3.0.x` series release.

As for actually using the "new" connection URI options, the main restriction is to actually include the `port` on the connection string:

```
const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';  // mongodb://localhost - will fail

(async function() {
  try {

    const client = await MongoClient.connect(uri,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
    // ... anything

    client.close();
  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

})()
```

That's a more "strict" rule in the new code. The main point being that the current code is essentially part of the "node-native-driver" ( npm [`mongodb`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) ) repository code, and the "new code" actually imports from the [`mongodb-core`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-core) library which "underpins" the "public" node driver.

The point of the "option" being added is to "ease" the transition by adding the option to new code so the newer parser ( actually based around [`url`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url) ) is being used in code adding the option and clearing the deprecation warning, and therefore verifying that your connection strings passed in actually comply with what the new parser is expecting.

In future releases the 'legacy' parser would be removed and then the new parser will simply be what is used even without the option. But by that time, it is expected that all existing code had ample opportunity to test their existing connection strings against what the new parser is expecting.

So if you want to start using new driver features as they are released, then use the available `beta` and subsequent releases and ideally make sure you are providing a connection string which is valid for the new parser by enabling the `useNewUrlParser` option in `MongoClient.connect()`.

If you don't actually need access to features related to preview of the MongoDB 4.0 release, then pin the version to a `3.0.x` series as noted earlier. This will work as documented and "pinning" this ensures that `3.1.x` releases are not "updated" over the expected dependency until you actually want to install a stable version.

Comment: Do you have more information about what you mean when you say "released into the wild"?  How did 3.1.0-beta4 escape from the zoo?  Can you cite any refs about that?

Comment: @Wyck The "reference" was of course that at the time the question was asked, doing `npm install mongodb` resulting in the **"beta"** ( clearly marked in the version string shown in the question ) being installed since it was marked as `stable` in the npm repository when it should not have been. This was indeed an **error** at the time and should always be considered so if any code release showing `alpha` or `beta` within the version string is similarly marked as stable. Naturally time has passed and this is a feature in stable releases now, until ( as noted ) it will eventually go away.

Answer (score 47):

The below highlighted code to the mongoose connection solved the warning for the mongoose driver:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: not working for me. still getting: (node:35556) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Comment: You must need to save server.js or app.js wherever you are giving DB path if still not working try by deleting and reinstalling node_modules by entering npm install whenever your package.json file is

Answer (score 31):

There is nothing to change. Pass only in the connect function `{useNewUrlParser: true }`.

This will work:

```js
    MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log('connected to ' + url);
            db.close();
        }
    })
```

Comment: Just what I needed, but the warning message is still there :-S

Comment: Works for me, no warnings anymore.

Answer (score 23):

You just need to set the following things before connecting to the database as below:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testaroo');
```

Also,

```
Replace update() with updateOne(), updateMany(), or replaceOne()
Replace remove() with deleteOne() or deleteMany().
Replace count() with countDocuments(), unless you want to count how many documents are in the whole collection (no filter).
In the latter case, use estimatedDocumentCount().
```

Comment: Should be the top answer. All the other answers for me failed miserably.

Comment: Pls mark the ans as `correct` if it has worked for you. It worked for me as well!

Answer (score 20):

You need to add `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` in the `mongoose.connect()` method.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/Notification',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
```

Comment: this answer is the same as other answers that have been posted months earlier

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Comment: @PeterMortensen please check the date who posted answer first

Answer (score 16):

The connection string format must be **mongodb://user:password@host:port/db**

For example:

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:password@127.0.0.1:27017/yourDB', { useNewUrlParser: true } )
```

Comment: No. `MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/yourDB', { useNewUrlParser: true } )` works too.

Comment: How is this different from previous answers?

Answer (score 10):

The following works for me

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/playground", { useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(res => console.log('Connected to db'));
```

The `mongoose` version is `5.8.10`.

Comment: This one also worked for me. I am using-- `body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.14"`

Answer (score 8):

The problem can be solved by giving the port number and using this parser: `{useNewUrlParser: true}`

The solution can be:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/cat_app", { useNewUrlParser: true });
```

It solves my problem.

Comment: console itself gave solution to add `useNewUrlParser property` in `connect`, but your solution helped. so Upvoted!

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you need to add `{ useNewUrlParser: true }`.

It's up to you if you want to use the new URL parser already. Eventually the warning will go away when MongoDB switches to their new URL parser.

As specified in *[Connection String URI Format](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/connection-string/)*, you don't need to set the port number.

**Just adding `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` is enough.**

Comment: I've added the port number and still get the error message. I find the error message very confusing and misleading: why do I get a message telling me to use the new format, when in fact I'm using the old format and it works perfectly...!!??

Comment: Good question! Note that it's a warning. Not an error. Only by adding in `useNewUrlParser: true` will the warning disappear. But that's a bit stupid as this extra parameter will become obsolete once mongo switches to their new url parser.

Comment: how did you know that the port number is what the new url parser expects? I can't find anything that actually describes what the new url parser is

Comment: @Brad, indeed. I was assuming you needed to add the port number, but the Mongo specs still mention the port number as being optional. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

## Updated for [ECMAScript 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#8th_Edition_-_ECMAScript_2017) / await

The incorrect [ECMAScript 8 demo code MongoDB inc provides](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/reference/ecmascriptnext/connecting/) also creates this warning.

**MongoDB provides the following advice, which is incorrect**

> To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Doing this will cause the following error:

> TypeError: final argument to `executeOperation` must be a callback

Instead **the option must be provided to `new MongoClient`**:

See the code below:

```js
const DATABASE_NAME = 'mydatabase',
    URL = `mongodb://localhost:27017/${DATABASE_NAME}`

module.exports = async function() {
    const client = new MongoClient(URL, {useNewUrlParser: true})
    var db = null
    try {
        // Note this breaks.
        // await client.connect({useNewUrlParser: true})
        await client.connect()
        db = client.db(DATABASE_NAME)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.stack)
    }

    return db
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The complete example for Express.js, API calling case and sending JSON content is the following:

```
...
app.get('/api/myApi', (req, res) => {
  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://user:password@domain.com:port/dbname',
    { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {

      if (err) throw err
      const dbo = db.db('dbname')
      dbo.collection('myCollection')
        .find({}, { _id: 0 })
        .sort({ _id: -1 })
        .toArray(
          (errFind, result) => {
            if (errFind) throw errFind
            const resultJson = JSON.stringify(result)
            console.log('find:', resultJson)
            res.send(resultJson)
            db.close()
          },
        )
    })
}
```

Answer (score 7):

The following work for me
for the `mongoose` version `5.9.16`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useUnifiedTopology', true);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName')
    .then(() => console.log('Connect to MongoDB..'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB..', err))
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I have it. The hint didn't show on my console until I updated npm a couple of days prior.

.connect has three parameters, the URI, options, and err.

```
mongoose.connect(
    keys.getDbConnectionString(),
    { useNewUrlParser: true },
    err => {
        if (err) 
            throw err;
        console.log(`Successfully connected to database.`);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

#### We were using:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/mean-course").then(
  (res) => {
   console.log("Connected to Database Successfully.")
  }
).catch(() => {
  console.log("Connection to database failed.");
});
```

*→ This gives a URL parser error*

#### The correct syntax is:

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/mean-course" , { useNewUrlParser: true }).then(
  (res) => {
   console.log("Connected to Database Successfully.")
  }
).catch(() => {
  console.log("Connection to database failed.");
});
```

Comment: Add some description

Answer (score 2):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose
  .connect(connection_string, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then((con) => {
    console.log("connected to db");
  });
```

try to use this

Answer (score 1):

I was using mlab.com as the MongoDB database. I separated the connection string to a different folder named `config` and inside file *keys.js* I kept the connection string which was:

```js
module.exports = {
  mongoURI: "mongodb://username:password@ds147267.mlab.com:47267/projectname"
};
```

And the server code was

```js
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const app = express();

// Database configuration
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

// Connect to MongoDB

mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true } // Need this for API support
  )
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("hello!!"));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`)); // Tilde, not inverted comma
```

You need to write `{ useNewUrlParser: true }` after the connection string as I did above.

Simply put, you need to do:

```js
mongoose.connect(connectionString,{ useNewUrlParser: true } 
// Or
MongoClient.connect(connectionString,{ useNewUrlParser: true }
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines did the trick for all other deprecation warnings too:

```
const db = await mongoose.createConnection(url, { useNewUrlParser: true });
mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using mongoose version 5.x for my project. After requiring the mongoose package, set the value globally as below.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Set the global useNewUrlParser option to turn on useNewUrlParser for every connection by default.
mongoose.set('useNewUrlParser', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me nicely:

```
mongoose.set("useNewUrlParser", true);
mongoose.set("useUnifiedTopology", true);
mongoose
  .connect(db) //Connection string defined in another file
  .then(() => console.log("Mongo Connected..."))
  .catch(() => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

If `username` or `password` has the `@` character, then use it like this:

```
mongoose
    .connect(
        'DB_url',
        { user: '@dmin', pass: 'p@ssword', useNewUrlParser: true }
    )
    .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
    .catch(err => console.log('Could not connect to MongoDB', err));
```

Answer (score 0):

> (node:16596) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is
> deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new
> parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
> (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:16596) [MONGODB DRIVER] Warning: Current Server
> Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in
> a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring
> engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient
> constructor.

**Usage:**

```
async connect(connectionString: string): Promise<void> {
        this.client = await MongoClient.connect(connectionString, {
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
  })
        this.db = this.client.db()
}
```