# current URL string parser is deprecated in mongo db and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb and nodejs 8 to connect to database but I get this error :

```
    (node:7280) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
```

my codes :

```
mongoose.connect(db,(err) => {
            if (err)
                console.error(err);
            else
                console.log("Connected to the mongodb");
        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It looks like you may have forgotten to include the error you're seeing in your question.

Comment: yes it is true , the error is :
(node:7280) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Comment: thank's for remembering

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Avoid "current URL string parser is deprecated" warning by setting useNewUrlParser to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change your code to:

```
mongoose.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true}, (err) => {
    if (err)
        console.error(err);
    else
        console.log("Connected to the mongodb"); 
});
```

You are getting this error because you are using a newer version (>=4.0.0) of MongoClient

Answer (score 7):

If it fails too, you need to add `{useUnifiedTopology: true }` to the code. It looks like:

```
mongoose.connect(db, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err) => {
  if (err)
     console.error(err);
  else
     console.log("Connected to the mongodb"); 
});
```