# Type Error: Cannot read property 'hasListCollectionsCommand' of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to get all collection names in mongodb (v4.0.2) and using [mongodb@3.1.10](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) nodejs driver. From the docs, I can see that `listCollections` might work, but running the following:

```
const Db = require('mongodb').Db
const Server = require('mongodb').Server
const db = new Db(dbName, new Server(host, port, options), {})
db.listCollections().toArray((error, collectionNames) => {
  console.error(error)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(collectionNames))
})
```

… leads to this error:

> if (this.serverConfig.capabilities().**hasListCollectionsCommand**) {
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasListCollectionsCommand' of null
>      at Db.listCollections ({path}/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:493:39)
>      at db.createCollection ({path}/sampleMongoDB.js:19:8)
>      at err ({path}/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:415:14)
>      at executeCallback ({path}/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:404:25)
>      at executeOperation ({path}/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:422:7)
>      at Db. ({path}/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:431:12)
>      at Db.deprecated [as createCollection] ({path}/node_modules/mongodb  /lib/utils.js:661:17)
>      at Object.< anonymous > ({path}/sampleMongoDB.js:18:6)
>      at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
>      at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)

My questions are:

1. Is there a docs site for MongoDB NodeJs drivers where we can refer examples from?
2. If not, what's the correct way to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to work it out. The [MongoClient's instance](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/MongoClient.html) returns a [`db`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html) instance, which inturn helps run `mongodb.Db` methods.

Here's a sample code that worked (Ref. to [MongoDB guides](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/tutorials/connect/))

```js
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true, // Add this, if you wish to avoid {https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars} issue
}

const client = new MongoClient(connectionUri, options)

return client.connect().then(() => {
  const db = client.db(dbName)
  return db.listCollections()
    .toArray()
    .then((collections) => {
      // Collections array
    })

})
```

@Community mods - if required, kindly close this question.