# DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated on starting server

Tags: mongodb, warnings, connect, deprecated

Y have this message when start npm "DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect."

Comment: I finded the answer on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for this and other obsolete warnings, I have done this:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/databasename', { useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true }, (err, res) => {
```

Comment: In which file did you do this?

Comment: In the index.js file