# Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators at Aggregate.append

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

https://mongoplayground.net/p/MlQFd6J4rZc

```
Products.aggregate({
    $match: {
        $or: [
            { '_id': {$regex: queryRegex } },
            { 'name': {$regex: queryRegex } },
        ]
    },
    {
    $addFields: {
      favorite: {
        $cond: [
          {
            $in: [
              'xxx',
              '$favoritedBy'
            ]
          },
          true,
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  
})
```

Adding the $addFields portion broke the code. I am not sure why. It's working on the mongoplayground example I set up. Is there any reason for this? removing $addFields removes the error, but I should be able to create a new field, so I am confused as to what's going on.

Mongoose is version 5.11.12, so it's not caused by the version number, I think.

[Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators at Aggregate.append](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59851142/error-arguments-must-be-aggregate-pipeline-operators-at-aggregate-append/59852662#59852662)

useNewUrlParser was set to true.

Comment: You miss [ ] in aggregate. Products.aggregate( [ { ... stage1 } , { ... stage2 } ] )

Comment: Sorry, it's inside [], it's a typo.

Comment: You are missing a `}` to close the `$match` stage.

Comment: Wait, it's the [] as YuTing said actually. Not sure if I should remove the question, but it seems like something other people may encounter. The error message is really not helpful here.