# We couldn't find anything for node:16096 deprecationwarning: current url string parser is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. to use

Tags: mongodb

We couldn't find anything for node:16096 deprecationwarning: current url string parser is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. to use the new parser pass option usenewurlparser: true to mongoclient.connect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoid "current URL string parser is deprecated" warning by setting useNewUrlParser to true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50448272/avoid-current-url-string-parser-is-deprecated-warning-by-setting-usenewurlpars)

Comment: same warning it showing