# Mongoose is unable to connect to mLab environment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mlab

I have an application I attempting to connect to an mLab environment using Mongoose. I have the following code configured to attempt to connect to an mLab MongoDB Instance.

```
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', () => {});
```

The variable `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is equal to 
`mongodb://user:password@ds123456.mlab.com:12345/someRandomName` (identifiers psuedonymized for privacy).

**Applicable Software Versions**

Node: v10.7.0

NPM: 6.2.0

Mongoose: 5.2.6

When I try to run the application I get the following error.

> node ./bin/www

```
(node:2555) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.
connection error: Error: Slash in host identifier
    at parseConnectionString (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:219:15)
    at parseHandler (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:129:14)
    at module.exports (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:25:12)
    at deprecated (internal/util.js:70:15)
    at connect (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:179:3)
    at connectOp (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:283:3)
    at executeOperation (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:420:24)
    at MongoClient.connect (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:168:10)
    at Promise (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:493:12)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:490:19)
    at Mongoose.connect (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:230:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nathanielsuchy/Documents/control-panel/app.js:20:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
```

I am lead to two conclusions. One I need to use the new URL parser, second there's an issue I'm not seeing in my database connection string format. How should I proceed to fix the issue?

Comment: The main issue here is `Error: Slash in host identifier`. The other thing is just a warning.

Comment: @Akrion The issue there is that there is not a slash in the hostname. I'm unable to determine the issue. My connection string matches the format specified at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/

Comment: Does your password contain the '@' or other special chars?

Comment: mongoose 5.2.6 `mongoose.connect(Stringconnection, { useNewUrlParser: true })`

Comment: @Akrion not an @ symbol but various other special chars.

Answer (score 0):

The correct format is `mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,host2[:port2],...[,hostN[:portN]]][/[database][?options]]`

Does your password contain the '@' or other special chars? If so:

```
const dbUrl = `mongodb://adminUsername:${encodeURIComponent('adminPassword')}@localhost:27017/mydb`;
```

Also check this: [MongoDB password with "@" in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it)

Comment: That works but not when using an enviroment variable.