# MongoError - Authentication error (password with @)

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Here is my code in my NodeJS application, to connect to my MongoDB engine :

```
 const collection = 'mynewcollection';
 const password = 'passwordwithan@';
 const mongoUrl = `mongodb://admin:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@mymongobase.net/${collection}`;

 // Connect using the connection string
 MongoClient.connect(mongoUrl, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db) {
   console.log(err.toString())
 });
```

I get an authentication error. I tried several things to handle the '@' character and reading the documentation I thought that it was the good one...
But it is still failing even if the user and password are the good one.

Is the API correctly used ? Do you understand what is wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB password with "@" in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486623/mongodb-password-with-in-it)

Comment: After more investigation, the @ is not a problem.
In fact, Mongo does not find my super user "admin" when I try to connect with it... If I create a new user and try to connect with it, it's OK.
I don't understand why the super user (which seems to be common to every database of my engine) is not recognized when I try to login.

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the solution.
If you use :

```
const mongoUrl = `mongodb://admin:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@mymongobase.net/${collection}`;
```

Mongo will try to connect with admin/password **defined on the collection**.

If you don't put the collection in the mongo url :

```
const mongoUrl = `mongodb://admin:${encodeURIComponent(password)}@mymongobase.net`;
```

Then you can use the super user defined on all the mongo engine.